# Displaying default container when loading items into GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I want to display items on GridView which are essentially an image with texts downloaded at run time from the internet

While the image is downloading i want to display a default image which will be replaced when the real image is fully downloaded

the thing is that my GridView is defined with num_of_columns and its item size change on different devices, **So the question is how can i know the size of the grid item and put a right sized default container**?

This is may GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridAction"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grid_vertical_spacing"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grid_horizontal_spacing"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/tabs_margin_left_right"
    />
```

I tried getting the size in the getView method but the sizes are not right

```
width = holder.mainRL.getWidth();
height = holder.mainRL.getHeight();
Log.i(Utils.TAG, "width: " + width + " height: " + height);
```

Another thing to ask is how to keep my items square sized and not rectangle? Even though my images are all square i get rectangle sized items

Answer (score 0):

Best to use with images and loading it is picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
 Picasso.with(context)
.load(url_of_image)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)//your image on load
.into(imageView);//your imageView
```

Picasso also enable to crop,resize your image:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.resize(50, 50) //resize
.centerCrop() //crop
.into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead, which has 2 relevant subclasses: `HorizontalGridView` and `VerticalGridView`.

You can have a custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` to handle **what** items to show, and/or a custom `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` to handle **how** to show the items.

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for complete instructions and sample code.

Comment: Thanks, but how will the Recyclerview be better then the GridView? lots of screens in my app use the existing GridView

Comment: @MichaelA RecyclerView is newer version with is solution for listview and gridview in one component. Using GridView is not wrong thing, and picasso cooperate with recycler view or with gridview.